# How do get this date/time format?

Tags: php, datetime, paypal

I saw a date/time format in a PHP code that has something like this:

```
2015-06-19T00:38:04Z
```

How can I generate a datetime having that kind of format?

I know this kind of format `date("Y-m-d H:i:s");` outputs different `2015-06-19T00:38:04Z` because it has a `T` and a `Z`.

So it's like I want to get the current date/time having a `T` and a `Z`

Comment: Do you know what the `T` and the `Z` stand for?

Comment: @JayBlanchard That i am not sure, i saw that on on PayPal's REST API. That part where you create a a billing agreement :)

Comment: It is [ISO 8601 date/time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). The T is just a separator between the date and time, and the Z means that it is in UTC.

Answer (score 2):

Escape T and Z in format

```
echo date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z"); // 2015-06-17T16:50:50Z
```

**UPDATE** Thanks to Lithis. To take a GMT/UTC time

```
echo gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z");  // 2015-06-17T17:06:06Z
```

Comment: This will not return the correct time. `date` returns local time, but the `Z` indicates that the string is in UTC. You should use `gmdate` instead.